# counting `true` of certain key in multidimensional object

Tags: javascript

I have a array of (`group`) objects. Inside each group object I have a array of (`item`) objects.

Each object ( group and item ) contains a key called `show_on_graph`

I want to move over each object to count how many `show_on_graph` are set to true.

Is there and established way to do this or do I need to just create a custom way to iterate or map through everything to count the `true` values?

[image]

Comment: I don't get if you have the `show_on_graph` property also in the elements inside `items`. Can you post a sample datastructure to copy-paste?

Comment: Yes. the `show_on_graph` property is inside each `item` object aswell.

Comment: I guess using a reduce would do the trick ?

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). Please add the input, expected output and the code you've tried so far as text to create a [mcve].

Comment: You need to sum up the number of items with that property and the number of group together?

Answer (score 1):

Should be

```
const count = toppics.reduce((sum, val) => {
    if (val.show_on_graph) {
        sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}, 0);
```

If you use `lodash`, `_.countBy` should be the one you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could take an iterative and recursive approach by iterating al key/value pairs of the objects and count if found or count the nested objects.

```
function getCount(object, key, value) {         
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return 0;
    return Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce((c, [k, v]) => c + (k === key && v === value || getCount(v)), 0);
}
```

Call with

```
getCount(object, 'show_on_graph', true);
```